# add data to multiple databases simultaniusly

Tags: php, mysql, html

i currently have several sites that work together but each have their own registration pages such as

- main website
- forums
- wiki
- clubs

as said each of them has their own registration pages and each of them has their own database
what i am wanting to do is combine all the registration pages into 1 central registration area where they just register on the single page and it creates an account for all of them but the problem is i don't know how to wright data to multiple databases simultaneously and how to specify what data goes to what database and what tables it wright it to for each database

each database has a different name, username and table structure
but all of the databases have the same password

if you haven't figure out this is php and mysql

Comment: what have you tried? a standard mysql insert lets you specify the db name as well as the table name. Insert into DB.TABLE ...

Comment: Not so sure what's confusing about using multiple connections... And I'd like to suggest NOT doing this, there HAS to be a better way to design a database than this.

Comment: well i cant figure out how to setup a multiple connection method using the stranded way of connection
well i cant change how the databases are set up because the forums,wiki,main site have already been configured for the specific database and they where installed and i cant change it

Comment: Does it require multiple mysql connections (for different user accounts)? If not then you can specify a database in the query

Comment: yes it requires multiple account connections because the host i am using required a different username for each database

Comment: Are the `Shift` and punctuation keys on your keyboard broken?

Answer (score 3):

Different queries on seperate databases...

```
$c1 = new mysqli("localhost", "user1", "pass1", "db1");
$c2 = new mysqli("localhost", "user2", "pass2", "db2");

$c1->query("INSERT INTO `members` (`user`, `pass`) VALUES ('user', 'pass') ");
$c2->query("INSERT INTO `members` (`user`, `pass`) VALUES ('user', 'pass') ");
```

Comment: And most importantly, different connection objects

Comment: so to wright to the selected database i would put
INSERT INTO `c1`.`members` (`login` ,`passwd`);
INSERT INTO `c2`.`accounts` (`login` ,`passwd`);

Comment: id the db's share the same credentials you don't need separate conections objects.

Comment: @kyle1046 If that helps, could you make that as the answer please ;)

Answer (score 0):

I should have made an master_user_table in one database, and let the registrationpage store the user there. and then let the other databases copy userdata from this table, that way you know what data is the main data, and what data is just copies. a even better way is to use view insted of tables in the other tables, that way the data is only stored on one place, and is always up to date.

```
CREATE VIEW users LIKE SELECT username, password, email FROM master_user_database.users;
```